# Wordpress : How can I loop through a list of post ID

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have an array full of post IDs like `$post_id = array(3,56,89,98);` Now what I have to do is just display the post details in a tabular format. How can I construct the loop for Wordpress here? Please apologize my novice knowledge in Wordpress and be soft. I really need some direction.

Comment: How have you come by this array?  In Wordpress generally, you access post data in something called the Loop, which is essentially a while loop over the results of a query and includes all of the details of the post so you don't have to hydrate them yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i have also started learning php all you need to do something like

```
foreach ($post_id as $id) { 
  // do what ever you want to do here

}
```

Edit

```
<?php
$post_id = array(3,56,89,98);
 $posts = get_posts( $post_id);
 foreach( $posts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata($post);  ?> 
     // you can call use post data inside here like
     <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I need wordpress looping process not the general PHP foreach loop. I am sorry I can't accept it. Thanks

Comment: @SamikChattopadhyay:Wordpress use php and you need to fetch post data based on the loop

Comment: That seems like what I needed. Thanks for your reply. The get_posts function did everything which I was thinking to do myself. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Actually I think there's something wrong with Umesh's answer.
Instead of:

```
$post_id = array(3,56,89,98);
```

It should be:

```
$post_id = array( 'post__in' => array(3,56,89,98) );
```

Right?

Answer (score 4):

To construct the loop, you should be able to use the [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function.  Something like
`query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $post_id ) );`
should do the trick.

The parameters are outlined in the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) page of the codex.